# Weird 'Module not found: Can't resolve' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this is common issue that is generally solvable by checking the imports thoroughly, but for some reason, I just can't see what is wrong with mine:

The full error reads:

```
./src/components/BookShelf.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Book' in '/Users/../src/components'
```

Yet my BookShelf.js file's imports are as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Book from './components/Book'
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your folder structure look like?

Comment: @MarcM. Thanks for the question. It was solved with the exact thing I think you're eluding to. I just needed to reference the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your `Book` and `BookShelf` components are located in `components` folder so your import should be `import Book from './Book'`

Comment: That totally fixed it. On to the next error. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Read the error more carefully.

You're importing from `/Users/.../src/components`.  There is no `./components` subdirectory of that (since you're already in that directory).